# Can I log query execution time in PostgreSQL 8.4?

Tags: postgresql

I want to log each query execution time which is run in a day.

For example like this,

```
2012-10-01 13:23:38 STATEMENT: SELECT * FROM pg_stat_database  runtime:265 ms.
```

Please give me some guideline.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you set

```
log_min_duration_statement = 0
log_statement = all
```

in your postgresql.conf, then you will see all statements being logged into the Postgres logfile.

If you enable

```
log_duration
```

that will also print the time taken for each statement. This is off by default.

Using the `log_statement` parameter you can control which *type* of statement you want to log (DDL, DML, ...)

This will produce an output like this in the logfile:

```
2012-10-01 13:00:43 CEST postgres LOG:  statement: select count(*) from pg_class;
2012-10-01 13:00:43 CEST postgres LOG:  duration: 47.000 ms
```

More details in the manual:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHEN
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT

If you want a daily list, you probably want to configure the logfile to rotate on a daily basis. Again this is described in the manual.

Comment: thank! for guide Mr.a_horse_with_no_name , 
but only query is log when i changed in postgresql.conf, What i really want is query and related execution time.

Comment: @9ine: what do you mean with "only query is log"? That's what you asked for: to log queries.

Comment: I mean query and related execution time.

Comment: @9ine: query *and* execution time are logged. Again: what's your question?

Answer (score 7):

I believe OP was actually asking for execution duration, not the timestamp.

To include the duration in the log output, open `pgsql/<version>/data/postgresql.conf`, find the line that reads

```
#log_duration = off
```

and change it to

```
log_duration = on
```

If you can't find the given parameter, just add it in a new line in the file.

After saving the changes, restart the postgresql service, or just invoke

```
pg_ctl reload -D <path to the directory of postgresql.conf>
```

e.g.

```
pg_ctl reload -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/
```

to reload the configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I think a better option is to enable `pg_stat_statements` by enabling the PG stats extension. This will help you to find the query execution time for each query nicely recorded in a view