# Steps involved in pg_dump?

Tags: postgresql, php-pgsql

I want to know how exactly the pg_dump works step by step. I know that it begins by locking tables. I am currently doing a pg_dump on my database and i switched on the --verbose mode. Here is what i get currently:

```
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "tablename"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "tablename"
```

So, what all steps does pg_dump do after these? Does it start working on the values inside these tables after this or it does that within these?

Comment: what do you mean with "start working on the values inside these tables"? Whay do you need exactly?

Comment: Look it up in the source. The textstrings are easy to find.

Comment: i mean that currently the dump is only working on creating the database. When does it start working on the values that are in the tables?

Comment: The best reference is the source code. It depends on the options you use (parallel mode or not, custom or SQL format, etc) too. What actual *problem* are you trying to solve? What're you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to estimate the time it will take

Comment: If it is not a huge database and you are OK with logging everything to log file, just log all statements. From the log file you should get an idea about time taken, sequence of steps etc. See this link for setting up logging. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670745/can-i-log-query-execution-time-in-postgressql-8-4