# monitor JDBC calls

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, monitoring

I have a Java App that connects to a Postgres DB and issues some SQL statements. I would like to monitor the connections to get statistics about how fast each query is executed. I have tried using JAMon (http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/), but don't really understand it and find the documentation quite lacking.

This is how I open my connection:

```
Class.forName("com.jamonapi.proxy.JAMonDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jamon:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDB?jamonrealdriver=org.postgresql.Driver", "user", "pw");
```

I don't notice any difference though. Everything still works fine, so I guess that this is at least not wrongly configured, but I don't get a log or anything anywhere. Is there something else I have to set up?

I also tried adding this line, but it did nothing either:

```
con = MonProxyFactory.monitor(con);
```

So basically, what I am looking for is a complete and comprehensible beginners guide to monitoring JDBC calls using JAMon (or even any other monitoring tool, as long as its easy to set up).

Note: The finished program is supposed to run on a remote DB to which I don't have unrestricted access, meaning I cannot edit postgresql.conf or access the DB's log files. This means that I can't use the solution to [Can I log query execution time in PostgresSQL 8.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670745/can-i-log-query-execution-time-in-postgressql-8-4)

I have also tried using JDbMonitor (http://www.jdbmonitor.com/), which I managed to set up to the point at which the monitor successfully connected (it found my open DB connection from the Java App), but no queries were ever displayed/logged by it. So a little help for that monitor would also be great :D.

edit: Is log4jdbc (https://github.com/arthurblake/log4jdbc) a viable option? The newest version says its only for Java 1.7, so I'm not sure if it will even work, but will try it out while waiting for answers here...

Comment: Postgres has tools for that too you know.

Comment: @Kayaman I forgot to mention that, while I am currently working on my local DB, the program later needs to function on a remote DB on which I cannot access log files or edit postgresql.conf. I will update the question.

Comment: You can add pointcut (with aspectj or spring-aop) on DAO\Service methods and log execution time of whole method (include query execution time and time to fetch result).

Comment: @user1516873 I currently call Instant start = Instant.now(); at the beginning of any method and log Duration.between(start, Instant.now()); afterwards, but I don't think that this is the best way to do it. Plus, it doesn't include enough details (for example: it doesn't split query exec and fetch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use P6Spy

<del>https://p6spy.github.io/p6spy/2.0/install.html</del>

https://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

It generates a comprehensive log once correctly integrated with the application.

Comment: This was extremely easy to set up and configure and it is currently logging everything I need in the way that I want it. Maybe I'll hit a restriction somewhere along the way, but for now, this is the best and easiest solution for me, thanks!

Comment: I actually hit a limitation with this: I am inserting a file as a BLOB into the DB, but the Spy only catches the final INSERT command ("INSERT INTO test(filename, file) VALUES ('test.pdf',27142)")... all the commands to actually create and fill the LOB are not logged! Is there any way to enable logging of these as well?

Answer (score 0):

I've extensively used Log4jdbc and it works pretty well. You just need to replace the jdbc connection string and have the original .jar driver file in your classpath and it works like a charm. If you are using SL4FJ as a logging facade is a must-have.

Comment: I followed the tutorial on http://www.cubrid.org/analyzing_jdbc_logs (even though I'm using NetBeans, but whatever) and I keep getting "log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (myProj.PostgresCon).". I understand the warning in general (no appenders are defined for this class), but don't really understand how to add the appenders from my log4j.xml file to my classes logger.

Comment: This happened because you are using Log4j as a logging framework. Log4jdbc uses SL4FJ. You should replace Log4j jar from your classpath and add [log4j-over-slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j). Then you just have to create a [logback.xml](https://github.com/ysankar/ach/blob/master/ach-lib-test/src/main/resources/log4jdbc-logback.xml) file to the root of your classpath(src/main/resource if you are using Maven).

Comment: I managed to set up the logging, but still have two problems:

1) the log ist just written to console, not to the specified file.

2) I sometimes need to cast my connection to PGConnection (for LOB support), but get the following error: "net.sf.log4jdbc.ConnectionSpy cannot be cast to org.postgresql.PGConnection"... is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Regarding logging to a file, you have to setup a [file appender in your logback.xml](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html). You can obviously unwrap the connection from the ConnectionSpy object invoking getRealConnection()

Comment: Ah ok, totally missed getRealConnection(), sorry, but if I call it, it doesn't log any LOB handling queries, obviously. Also, I defined the FileAppender in logback.xml (following the tut in your link), but it still doesn't log to file (ConsoleAppender works fine).

Comment: Could you post here your logback.xml?